# When Excel file is opened externally during C# application, an exception occurs

Tags: c#, excel

I wrote a C# application that queries a DB and puts the results in an excel file. The program itself works fine. However if I open a second completely unrelated excel file while the application is running, an exception occurs and the process stops.

Now, in the program itself I've set the visibility to false, and after opening the second unrelated Excel file, the one that was being generated is suddenly open and visible, and then I get the exception.

Anyone know what is causing the problem or how to resolve it?

The relevant parts of the code is as follows, the exception occurs at the line worksheet.get_Range(currCol.GetString() + excelRow, Missing.Value).Formula = item.ToString();

The exception itself is : "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472"

```
        Application exc = new Application();

        //Makes the Excel file not visible
        exc.Visible = false;
        exc.UserControl = false;
        exc.DisplayAlerts = false;


        Workbooks workbooks = exc.Workbooks;
        Workbook workbook = workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);


        Sheets sheets = workbook.Worksheets;
        Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);

        int excelRow = 1;
        ExcelChar currCol = new ExcelChar('A');
        System.Data.DataTable testTable = dbConnection.searchQuery("Select * from testTable").Copy();

        if (worksheet == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: worksheet == null");
        }



        foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in testTable.Rows)
        {
            foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
            {
                worksheet.get_Range(currCol.GetString() + excelRow, Missing.Value).Formula = item.ToString();
                currCol.Add(1);
            }
            excelRow++;
            currCol = new ExcelChar('A');
        }
```

Comment: 1.  We need to see your code.  2.  We need to know what the exception is, and on what line of your code the exception is being thrown.

Comment: @user890123480213480128304: This is something that has happened in the past to colleagues of mine. It has something to do with excel being able to open only one instance of itself. Google something along those lines.

Comment: Are you using threads when opening excel file ?

Comment: Don't use excel for automation. Use 3rd party implementations like NPOI for 2003 or EPPlus for 2007+ excel formats.

Comment: @OnlyBolivianHere: I've found that, when using COM, at least, it works okay if the other Excel file is open _before_ you run the application. Kind of odd.

Comment: I'm working with a four year old app right now, actually, that does the same thing.  If you find a solution, you'll have found a solution I've been looking for for four years.  For now, I can tell you we gave up long ago and actually set up a virtual machine for this app to run on, and it's the last time I will ever willingly use Office Interop in a production app again.  I bet your clipboard clears, so you can't copy/paste while it's running, too, right?

Comment: I agree with @RobertHarvey. Please show us the code so that we can give you an exact reason on why that happens.

Comment: @JAB "it works okay if the other Excel file is open before you run the application" - not necessarily.  If Excel is busy, you'll get this error.  It's busy when opening a file, but there are other cases when it's busy - for example displaying a modal dialog, or running a long-running VBA macro.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/9168f9f2-e5bc-4535-8d7d-4e374ab8ff09/).

It looks like your error is VBA_E_IGNORE, in which case you need to register [an IMessageFilter implementation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2008/11/19/implementing-imessagefilter-in-an-office-add-in.aspx) so you can implement retry logic.

I've seen this issue in the past, when using the same instance of Excel with interop and interactively - for example when instatiating an Excel Application object using:

```
Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
```

In your case, you're creating a new instance of Excel using:

```
exc = new Application();
```

What you should try to do is to make sure you close this instance as quickly as possible.  This is not always easy, because of the problem described in [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317109).  Otherwise you might consider something other than COM Interop to write to Excel (e.g. OLEDB or a third party library such as Aspose or EPPlus).

When Excel is busy - e.g. has a modal dialog displayed, or is busy loading a workbook, it will not respond to incoming COM messages, so it returns an error which is translated into this exception.  An `IMessageFilter` implementation (specifically: `RetryRejectedCall`) will typically retry a few times, then either fail or prompt the user to retry ("Server busy").

Answer (score 0):

When using the Office InterOp services, you must close the objects you've created in reverse order.

```
private static void Excel_FromDataTable(DataTable dt)
    {
        // Global missing variable.
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        // Creates an excel object, 
        Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        // Then a workbooks object,
        Excel.Workbooks workbooks = excel.Workbooks;
        // Then adds a workbook object,
        Excel.Workbook workbook = workbooks.Add(true);
        // Then adds a worksheet object,
        Excel.Worksheet activeSheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
        // Then names the worksheet to what we need.
        activeSheet.Name = "scbyext";

        // Add column headings,
        int iCol = 0;
        // for each row of data,
        int iRow = 0;
        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            iRow++;

            // Then add each row's cell data.
            iCol = 0;
            foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
            {
                iCol++;
                excel.Cells[iRow, iCol] = r[c.ColumnName];
            }
        }

        // Disable Excel prompts.
        excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
        // Save the workbook to the correct folder.
        workbook.SaveAs("C:\\Escaped\\Path",
        Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel8, missing, missing,
        false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
        missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);

        // Release the objects we made, in reverse order, to allow Excel to quit correctly.
        ReleaseObj(activeSheet);
        ReleaseObj(workbook);
        ReleaseObj(workbooks);
        excel.Quit();
        ReleaseObj(excel);
    }
```

If you don't, the process will stay stuck open.  I'm not sure what it's doing when it stays stuck, but by the end of the day the CPU Time used by it can get quite high.

Comment: This doesn't answer the actual query of the OP :)

Comment: The basic advice is good, because leaving Excel open increases the risk of an interactive use of the same instance, but this implementation is incomplete: doesn't release the `excel.Cells` objects it creates, and doesn't use try/finally to guarantee release in the event of an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I was creating an excel file using C# with a lot of charts that took a long time to create. If a user opened an existing excel file while my C# file was still being written it caused an exception to be thrown and my application would crash.

I fixed it with the following:

```
xlApp = new Application();
xlApp.IgnoreRemoteRequests = true;
```